# Setup Project in VS2005 to set HKLM\Software... registry setting?

Tags: visual-studio, registry

I'm writing a toolbar for Internet Explorer, and it requires that the following key is set.

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Interet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\iexplore.exe

The installer is running with elevated rights.

I have set this value

But on Windows 7 Enterprise, the installer writes the registry setting to this path instead:

HKLM\Software\Wow6432node\Microsoft\Interet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\iexplore.exe

If I change the setting in Internet Explorer (allow active content to run files on my computer), I see that it's the first path that gets adjusted.

How do I make the setup project write to right path in the registry?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that happens when you run a 32-bit installer on a 64-bit operating system.  Registry redirection will redirect the writes from HKLM\Software to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node.  You'll need a 64-bit installer.

The TargetPlatform property, in case you are using a VS Setup project.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Hans. I'm changing it to 64-bit, but I guess it won't be able to run on 32-bit machines anymore. I was hoping to have one installer for all, if possible, since the application works on both platforms - it's just the registry setting that is causing problems.